# Area Code is not set when working in CLI command class and run di:complie

Tags: magento2, cli, command

i am working in command class, when i inject a class in constructor and run di complie, it gives error of "area code is not set", when i remove injected class form the constructor then my command is working, taking argume

Comment: can you please share code here ?

Comment: share the code of class, which show this error?

Answer (score 0):

Inject `\Magento\Framework\App\State` in your `__construct` and following code  into your execute function

```
try {
     $this->state->getAreaCode();
} catch (\Exception $exception) {
    $this->state->setAreaCode(\Magento\Framework\App\Area::AREA_ADMINHTML);
}
```